# How to calculate coordinates of the gunpoint

Tags: math, geometry, love2d

Good whatever time of day! I have some sprite:

[image]

`A` point has coordinates `Actor.x; Actor.y`.

```
AB length = 96
BC length = 86
AC length = 42

All calculations are approximate, I made it with help the ruler in Photoshop.
```

Sprite always towards mouse, angle (in radians) stores in `Actor.direction` variable. I draw sprite with scale `0.3`.

All bullets toward mouse (that is `Bullet.direction == Actor.direction`). I need to create bullets in the `B` point. How I can calculate coordinates of the `B` point with any angle?

**UPD**

If I will create bullets in the coordinates:

```
x = Actor.x + 96 * math.cos(Actor.direction) * 0.3
y = Actor.y + 96 * math.sin(Actor.direction) * 0.3
```

I get it:

[image]

Excuse my bad English! It isn't my native language. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

```
cs = math.cos(Actor.direction)
sn = math.sin(Actor.direction)
```

point B will be shifted from A by

```
dx = - 42 * sn + 86 * cs
dy = 42 * cs + 86 * sn
```

Perhaps you will need to change signs before both 42s

(I did not account for scale)

Comment: Thanks you very much!