# Calculate new circle offset based on angle of rotation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, trigonometry, calculus

I have a multiplayer Javascript game where the player is a circle, and is able shoot/"eject" circle bullets in the direction that the player is rotated. My code is working perfectly, except it shoots from the middle of the player. I would like it so that the circles are shot from the top right position of the player, where the gun is located. The issue is that when the players rotation changes, you cannot simply add (1, -1) to the position of the player.

Here is my code:

```
GameServer.prototype.ejectMass = function(client) {

    for (var i = 0; i < client.cells.length; i++) {
        var cell = client.cells[i]; // the player


        var angle = this.toRad(client.rotation); // rotation of the player

        var d = new Vec2(Math.sin(angle), Math.cos(-angle)).scale(-180);

        var sq = (~~d.sqDist(d));

        d.x = sq > 1 ? d.x / sq : 1;
        d.y = sq > 1 ? d.y / sq : 0;

        // cell.position is the players position
        var pos = new Vec2(
            cell.position.x + d.x * cell._size,
            cell.position.y + d.y * cell._size
        );

        var ejected = 0;

        // Create cell and add it to node list

        ejected = new Entity.EjectedMass(this, null, pos, this.config.ejectSize * cell.ejectSize); // the bullet being shot

        ejected.setBoostDefault(-this.config.ejectVelocity * cell.ejectSpeed, angle);

        ejected.ejectedOwner = cell; // set the person who shot the bullet 

        this.addNode(ejected); // add the bullet into the game

        if (typeof ejected !== 'undefined') {
            setTimeout(this.removeNode.bind(this, ejected), 1000); // remove the ejected bullet after 1 second
        }
    }
};
```

And here is an illustration of the current way it is working:
[image: eject illustration]

Comment: You want to create the bullets with an initial position relative to player position and player orientation? You seem to know trigonometry (sin and cos). What is your specific problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330819/how-to-calculate-coordinates-of-the-gunpoint/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the player (circle) is at its own local origin then the position of the gun is relative to the player's origin. Assuming the coordinate system is that of the canvas with forward along the x axis from left to right, and clockwise 90deg (left of player) is the Y axis going down.

[image]
Image: **C** is local circle origin **(0,0)** with **Forward** along the red arrow from **C**, **Gx** and **Gy** are the local coordinates of the gun from the circle center **C**. Top left shows the canvas coordinate (world) system origin. In code below, The `player` position is relative to that world origin. The final `gunPos` is also give relative to the world coordinates. **B vec** is the bullets `bullet.delta` vector

```
const bulletSpeed = 10;
var gunPos = {x : 10, Y : 10} // ten units forward ten units left of circle center
var player = {rotation : ?, x : ?, y : ?} // unknown player position and rotation



// get the unit vector of the rotated x axis. Along player forward
var xAx = Math.cos(player.rotation);
var xAy = Math.sin(player.rotation);

// transform the gunpos to absolute position (world coordinates) of rotated player 
var rotatedGunPos = {};
rotatedGunPos.x = gunPos.x * xAx - gunPos.y * xAy + player.x;
rotatedGunPos.y = gunPos.x * xAy + gunPos.y * xAx + player.y;

// and fire the bullet from 
var bullet = {}
bullet.x = rotatedGunPos.x;
bullet.y = rotatedGunPos.y;

// bullet vector is
bullet.deltaX = xAx * BULLET_SPEED;
bullet.deltaY = xAy * BULLET_SPEED;
```

Comment: Extremally useful. Highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide enough details about your layout such as what are orientations of X- and Y-axis? Where is 0 `angle`? Is `angle` clockwise or counterclockwise? Still the basic idea is the same. Let's assume that X-axis is to the right and Y-axis is down as it looks like from your attached image and adding (1, -1) to get top-right corner. Also assume that `angle = 0` for X-axis and `angle` is clockwise i.e. `angle = Pi/2` is aligned with positive direction of Y-axis = down. When the gun is pointed Up i.e. `angle = -Pi/2` your starting point is `(1, -1)` which is at distance `sqrt(2)` and additionally rotated to `Pi/4` corresponding to gun orientation. This is all you need to know.

```
    var angle = this.toRad(client.rotation); // rotation of the player
    var gunStartAngle = angle + Math.PI/4;
    var sqrt2 = Math.sqrt(2); 

    // cell.position is the players position
    var pos = new Vec2(
        cell.position.x + cell._size * sqrt2 * Math.cos(gunStartAngle),
        cell.position.y + cell._size * sqrt2 * Math.sin(gunStartAngle)
    );
```

Obviously if your layout is different, you should fix the details of the math but the idea remains the same.